# Отловить сообщение-видео Telegram Bot API

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Народ, хочу выловить сообщение, которое отправляет пользователь боту. Сообщение - видео. Хэндлер либы pyTelegramBotAPI не воспринимает данное сообщение вовсе. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашел, можно закрывать.
Если кому понадобится - достаточно у хендлера указать контент тип, получается вот такая вот строка:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['video'])
def catch_video(message):
    pass
```